# How to calculate scroll offset for horizontal scrolling on mousemove?

Tags: javascript, math, scroll, horizontal-scrolling, mousemove

I am attempting to create a horizontal screen functionality based on the mouse position. I have created most of the script and CSS, however, It only works when I manually enter the offset for the horizontal scrolling.

**Example:**

```js
const navbar = document.getElementById('navbar-list');

document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
    let x = e.clientX || e.pageX;

    navbar.style.setProperty('--pos-x', (-x/1.35) + 'px');
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flex-container, .menu, ul, li, a {
  height: 100%;
}

.flex-container, .menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.menu {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.menu ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: var(--pos-x);
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}

 .menu ul > li {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-left: -4px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
}

.menu ul > li > a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 18pt;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.4s; /* Safari */
    transition: background-color 0.4s;
}

.menu ul > li > a > .bottom-info {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -30px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  width: 25%;
  -webkit-transition: bottom 0.3s; /* Safari */
    transition: bottom 0.3s;
}

.menu ul > li > a:hover .bottom-info {
  bottom: 40px;
}

.menu ul > li > a:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<!-- Menu -->
<div class="menu" id="menu">
  <ul class="flex-container" id="navbar-list">
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="title">First Item</span>
        <div class="bottom-info">The first</div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">
        <span class="title">Second Item</span>
        <div class="bottom-info">The second</div>
      </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">
        <span class="title">Third Item</span>
        <div class="bottom-info">The Third</div>
      </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">
        <span class="title">Fourth Item</span>
        <div class="bottom-info">The fouth</div>
      </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">
        <span class="title">Fifth Item</span>
        <div class="bottom-info">The fifth</div>
      </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">
        <span class="title">Sixth Item</span>
        <div class="bottom-info">The sixth</div>
      </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">
        <span class="title">Seventh Item</span>
        <div class="bottom-info">The final item</div>
      </a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The problem is within the Javascript portion. This only currently works with 7 items and if I set the `--pos-x` `var` to be `-x/1.35`. If the amount of items changes, the script will either not scroll all the way to the last item (if more than 7 items) or scroll too far past the last item (less than 7 items).

```
const navbar = document.getElementById('navbar-list');

document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
    let x = e.clientX || e.pageX;

    // Here is where the problem lies (I should I calculate the 1.35 value?)
    navbar.style.setProperty('--pos-x', (-x/1.35) + 'px');

    console.log(navbar.offsetWidth);
});
```

This might just be a math problem, I just cannot figure it out for the life of me.

Answer (score 1):

That is the ratio between your screen width and the number of pixels that your container can scroll. For example if your screen width is 1000px, then the space taken by all your seven items will be 1750px (7 * 250px). This means that your container can move (scroll) by 750 px.

The value which you got is 1000 px / 750px = ~1.33. When you have for example 8 items then your container will take 2000px (8 ( 250px) which means that it will be able to scroll by 1000px only. The ratio will be 1000 px / 1000px which will be 1.

====

What you have to do now is to:

1. Determine the width of the container which contains all of your
   items.
2. Calculate max distance which your container can scroll (maxScrollDistance = containerWidth - screenWidth).
3. Calculate the ratio (screenWidth / maxScrollDistance)

PS. Keep in mind that your solution won't work on mobile.